# Fastest way to download a long list of zipfiles in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, python-asyncio, python-zipfile

I'm working on a project that requires downloading a lot of files (about 13,000) from a list of links in python. The downloaded zipped files will then be extracted and the contents of the .cpp file in that link is read.

I'm currently using threads to parallelize this process but there has to be a better way to do this. This operation of downloading the file, extracting it and writing it to memory seems to be IO bound even on my fast macbook SSD, Can't imagine the latency on a webserver.

If you guys have any recommendations on what I should be using or where I should be looking at would help a ton!!

```
def download_code_helper(url):
    # Define our retry strategy for all HTTP requests
    retry_strategy = Retry(
        total=3,
        backoff_factor=1,
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504]
    )
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    file_name = url.split('/')[-1].strip('.zip')
    path = 'tools/zytools/downloads/' + file_name +'.cpp'
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        print('downloading')
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            if response.status_code > 200 and response.status_code < 300:
                raise Not200Exception
            zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
            filenames = zfile.namelist()
            content = zfile.open(filenames[0], 'r').read()
            result = content.decode('utf-8')
            with open(path, 'w') as file:
                file.write(result)
            return (url, result)
        except Not200Exception:
            return (url, "Successfully received a response, but not data was received")
        except ConnectionError:
            return (url, "Max retries met, cannot retrieve student code submission")
    else:
        # print('not downloading')
        with open(path, 'r') as file:
            result = file.read()
        return (url, result)

def download_code(logfile):
    urls = logfile.zip_location.to_list()
    # student_code = ['' for i in range(len(urls))]
    student_code = []
    threads = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for url in urls:
            threads.append(executor.submit(download_code_helper, url))
        student_code = []
        i = 0
        for task in as_completed(threads):
            # print(i)
            student_code.append(task.result())
            i += 1
    df = pd.DataFrame(student_code, columns = ['zip_location', 'student_code'])
    logfile = pd.merge(left=logfile, right=df, on=['zip_location'])
    return logfile
```

I'm caching downloaded files so we dont have to download them again in case we need to open those in the future!

How do improve this code?

Comment: what do you mean by IO bound ? like network bound or disk speed bound ? what is the current disk write speed compared to your max write speed ?

Comment: Is this a FTP repository, by chance?

Comment: @AhmedAEK I haven't exactly measured it but its a 2020 m1 macbook air, so the SSD is pretty fast. I'm just assuming its IO bound cause its gonna have to write a new file every time for about 13000 times, that was just a guess

Comment: @ASH The files are hosted on AWS, so sadly not an FTP :(

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between FTP and AWS. I can imagine that it's somewhat similar...at least web-based, with some conventions and structure... If you want some sample code, I can post some logic of how to login to an FTP repository, and download files from the framework... Up to you...